# Múltiplos envios no Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou tendo problema para fazer envio de várias imagens, recebo todos os arquivos e no loop faço a interação, porém só envia e cadastra uma imagem.
Estou fazendo do jeito errado?

Segue o projeto no meu [github](https://github.com/Kriffx/trekos)

```
@PostMapping("/galeria/enviar")
public String enviarGaleria(GalleryModel gallery, @RequestParam("ref_gallery") Long ref, @RequestParam("img_gallery") MultipartFile[] galleries) throws IOException {
    for(MultipartFile gy : galleries) {
        Path galleryNameAndPath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, gy.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(galleryNameAndPath, gy.getBytes());

        gallery.setPostId(ref);
        gallery.setImage(gy.getOriginalFilename());
        galleryRepository.save(gallery);
    }

    return "redirect:/anuncios";
}
```

Comment: Bom se está salvando só uma provavelmente esta recebendo só uma, se possível edite a pergunta e inclua o código que você esta usando para enviar, nunca usei o MultipartFile desse jeito, tenho desse modo funcionando @RequestParam(name = "files", required = true) List<MultipartFile> files,

Comment: Pergunta editada, coloquei o projeto em meu github, sinta-se livre para avaliar o problema :D

Comment: Baixei seu projeto do Github e achei o problema, logo mais posto a solução e te mando um pull request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na sua modelagem de dados, sua implementação da classe `GalleryModel` nâo possui suporte para múltiplas fotos visto que você está guardando em uma string:

```
@Column(name="image", nullable=false)
private String image;
```

Rodei seu projeto e fiz alguns ajustes, mas de fato os arquivos chegam ao seu app (conforme evidência abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao verificar as operações realizadas no banco, você pode ver que foi realiza uma inserção, e depois a mesma galeria foi atualizada nas chamadas subsequentes:

```
Hibernate: insert into posts (author, category, content, cover, created_at, method, price, sale, status, title, updated_at, uri, views) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into galleries (created_at, image, post_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update galleries set created_at=?, image=?, post_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update galleries set created_at=?, image=?, post_id=? where id=?
Hibernate: update galleries set created_at=?, image=?, post_id=? where id=?
```

Dessa forma você está sempre guardando a última foto do loop, quando na verdade deveria estar guardando todas as fotos e relacionando elas com a galeria em sí.

Para resolver isso criei uma tabela associativa chamada `gallery_photo`, que irá guardar os registros das fotos da galeria, e alterei a associação na classe `gallery`:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="galleries")
public class GalleryModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="post_id", nullable=false)
    private long postId;

    @Column(name="created_at", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private Date createdAt;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "gallery", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<GalleryPhotoModel> photos;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="gallery_photo")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
public class GalleryPhotoModel {

    public GalleryPhotoModel(String image) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne
    private GalleryModel gallery;
}
```

Agora ao inserir a `galleries`, todas as fotos são salvas:

```
Hibernate: insert into posts (author, category, content, cover, created_at, method, price, sale, status, title, updated_at, uri, views) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into galleries (created_at, post_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into gallery_photo (gallery_id, image) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into gallery_photo (gallery_id, image) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into gallery_photo (gallery_id, image) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into gallery_photo (gallery_id, image) values (?, ?)
```

Ah outra coisa, sugiro você criar um novo layer no seu aplicativo para `services`, para isolar a camada de serviço (regras, conversões, etc...) da sua controladora, e dessa forma reaproveitar mais código. Refatorei o código que insere a galeria, lembre-se sempre do princípio [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself!)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), agora o método ficou assim:

```
private void salvarGalerias(GalleryModel gallery, Long postId, List<MultipartFile> galleries) throws IOException {
    for(MultipartFile gy : galleries) {
        Path galleryNameAndPath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, gy.getOriginalFilename());
        Files.write(galleryNameAndPath, gy.getBytes());
    }

    gallery.setPostId(postId);
    gallery.setCreatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    gallery.setPhotos(galleries.stream().map(MultipartFile::getOriginalFilename).map(GalleryPhotoModel::new).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    galleryRepository.save(gallery);

}
```

Ele deve ser chamado sempre que você for inserir uma nova `galleries`, esse método deve ser utilizado (daí a idéia de extrair isso para uma `GalleryService`):

```
@PostMapping("/publicar")
public String postPublish(PostModel post, GalleryModel gallery,
        @RequestParam("img_cover") MultipartFile cover,
        @RequestParam("img_gallery") MultipartFile[] galleries) throws IOException {
    Path fileNameAndPath = Paths.get(uploadDirectory, cover.getOriginalFilename());
    Files.write(fileNameAndPath, cover.getBytes());

    post.setAuthor(authUtility.getUserLogged().getId());
    post.setCover(cover.getOriginalFilename());
    post.setStatus(1);
    post.setPrice(post.getPrice().replace(",", "."));
    post.setUri(uriUtility.uri(post.getTitle()));
    post.setCreatedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    postRepository.save(post);

    salvarGalerias(gallery, post.getId(), Arrays.asList(galleries));

    return "redirect:/publicar";
}

@PostMapping("/galeria/enviar")
public String enviarGaleria(GalleryModel gallery, @RequestParam("ref_gallery") Long postId,
        @RequestParam(name="img_gallery", required=true) List<MultipartFile> galleries) throws IOException {
    salvarGalerias(gallery, postId, galleries);

    return "redirect:/anuncios";
}
```

Tem vários outros detalhes a se corrigir (nomes de entidades e tabelas, utilizar DTOs e não entidades para interação com as controladoras, camadas do app...), mas para o objetivo que você queria isso já vai lhe ajudar :)

Comment: Primeiramente queria agradecer pela ajuda, creio que gastou um tempo de seu descanso para esse problema, mas fico fortemente agradecido por esse apoio que sinceramente precisava, pois já estava quebrando cabeça e pensando em fazer de outra forma. Mas então, olhando o seu código ficou mais claro, mas ao mesmo tempo percebi um problema e meio que não sei como proceder, o problema é que no momento cadastra a galeria o gallery_id não recebe o id da galleries. Sinceramente por falta de experiencia não estou conseguindo enxergar o erro, poderias me dar uma luz?

Comment: em qual situação está acontecendo?

Comment: Olá, desculpe a demora, mas acontece quando realizo uma publicação do produto e vai tudo e as imagens e até no banco cadastra, porém única informação que não cadastra é o gallery_id.

Comment: Abra outra questão explicando melhor o problema, quando eu tiver um tempinho posso te ajudar